# How to calculate the radius with the given North and East values c#

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

Very simple question, if I have northern and eastern values how can I calculate the radius using c#?

for example I have `East: 534497 North: 168016`.  Now how can I calculate the radius in miles or km.

Edit1:
Thanks for the positive and negative support. I have no Idea about calculating the radius or this area of geociding etc, I posted my question here because I am assigned a task to take care of as this is one of our application requirement. We have UK addresses database and we have their co ordinates in Eastings and Northings format we are using MapPoint in our application, we are allowing the user to select a certain area on the Map and based on the selection we need to calculate the radius.

That's what I know. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Your coordinates represent a point. A radius is a segment between an origin and a point. What is the origin of your coordinates system?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the distance between a point and another point 534497 units east and 168016 units north of it? What units are they in? Is this on a flat surface or geographical points that could be far enough away from the curvature to matter?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pythagorean theorem.  You have the two sides and you need the diagonal.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem would not apply for a sufficiently large distance on a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is not even a valid question. If you want to know the distance between two points (latitude/longitude), I use a method like this:

```
    public static double Distance(Position pos1, Position pos2, DistanceType type)
    {
        double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
        double dLat = toRadian(pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude);
        double dLon = toRadian(pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude);
        double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.Cos(toRadian(pos1.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(toRadian(pos2.Latitude)) *
        Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(a)));
        double d = R * c;
        return d;
    }
```

The `Position` objects are objects containing `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties of the type `double`.